# Extracting data from JSON array with PHP, Error: Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have problems extracting data from a JSON array with PHP. Getting error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'shopId' in ...":

```
Array
(
    [kr-answer] => {
            "shopId":"69635714",
            "orderDetails":{
                   "orderTotalAmount":990,"
                   .....
                           }
                    }
)
```

PHP

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

$json_encode = json_encode($_POST, true);
$json_decode = json_decode($json_encode, true);

$shopId = $json_decode['kr-answer']['shopId']; // this line gives error
$orderTotalAmount = $json_decode['kr-answer']['orderDetails']['orderTotalAmount'];

echo $shopId;
echo $orderTotalAmount;

} // end if post method

?>
```

Also tried the following unsuccessfully, this gives error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'shopId' in ...":

```
$shopId = $_POST['kr-answer']['shopId'];
```

Comment: Can you include the full error, also try and show which line is causing the error.

Comment: @NigelRen, thanks, added the error for the specific line

Comment: It seems your JSON is double encoded. You would need to decode `kr-answer` before trying to access the key from it.